# Deleting a many to one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two tables, Patient and Appointment. 
A patient can have many appointments. When I go to delete a patient from the patient table hibernate then says the Appointment table does not exist.
Any help would be appreciated.

Setting the relationship in the patient class

```
            targetEntity = Appointment.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Appointment> appointmentset = new HashSet<Appointment>();
```

Many to one relation in the patient class

```
   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Patient_Id")
    private Patient patient;
```

Delete patient method

```
  public void deletePatient2(Integer id){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            TypedQuery query = session.getNamedQuery("deletePatient");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            query.executeUpdate();
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }
```

Delete patient named query

```
 @NamedQuery(
                        name = "deletePatient",
                        query = "delete from Patient p where p.id = :id"
                )
```

```
May 05, 2019 10:13:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
May 05, 2019 10:13:07 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'KYMb02vi2Z.Patient_Appointment' doesn't exist
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1618)
    at SessionManager.deletePatient2(SessionManager.java:1393)
```

Stack error, The table in the appointment class is set to be called appointment

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Appointment")
public class Appointment
```

But for some reason it is looking for a table called Patient_Appointment even when I rename the table it still errors and just add's another Patient_ at the start

Remapped OneToMany in patient class

```
 @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Appointment.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
 private List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    public void addAppointment(Appointment appointment){
        appointments.add(appointment);
        appointment.setPatient(this);
    }

    public void removeAppointment(Appointment appointment){
        appointments.remove(appointment);
        appointment.setPatient(null);
    }
```

Soloution

```
  @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "patient",
            targetEntity = Appointment.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
```

Added mappedBy

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. Here's how you map a bidirectional ont-to-many association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @JBNizet I have remapped the association and yet still can't delete, have I mapped it correctly? (Edited into post)

Comment: No, you haven't. **read** the documentation carefully: *Every bidirectional association must have one owning side only (the child side), the other one being referred to as the inverse (or the mappedBy) side. [...] `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", ...`*

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I thought that my targetEntity did the same but i was mistaken, thank you for your help, it works now